# How to switch power supply between two sensors

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, switching-regulator

I have two ultrasonic sensors, when one sensor acts as a transmitter other acts a receiver and vice-versa.

How can I supply power for the 1st sensor for 20 microseconds  and switch the power source to the second sensor for 20 microseconds with a delay of 10 milliseconds in between. For example, the powering up sequence appears like the below.

1. Power to 1st sensor for 20 micro seconds
2. Switch off power for 10 milli seconds
3. Power to 2nd sensor for 20 micro seconds
4. Switch off power for 10 milliseconds
5. Repeat steps 1 to 4

Note: Only one sensor is powered at a time.

**edit:** Ultrasonic sensor electrical supply:
The exact voltage applied to transducer depends on signal attenuation through the medium, which I am yet to determine, for this reason I would like to have the flexibility to go up to 200V (if need be). Ultrasonic transducer typically require 30mA.

**edit:** Ultrasonic sensor operation summary: 
I would like to apply 2MHz sine wave (or pulse) to one sensor and listen with the other and then switch the pulse and listening mode.

**edit:** Transducer spec.

[image]

Comment: How much current does each device use? And what voltage? Is there a microcontroller in this design?

Comment: @DanLaks, Please find the transducer spec [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p6clqecuies1v1v/Ultrasonic%20Transducer%20Spec.tiff?dl=0). I would like to supply a voltage upto 200V at minimum possible current the sensor needs to operate (not yet sure about the current). Yes there is a micro-controller in the design.

Comment: Just a heads up, that 200V thing is a pretty significant part of your question. It will definitely color the answers you receive. I'd edit your question and add that piece of info, as well as the link to the transducer.

Comment: This question is a bit confusing.  Is there a single coax connector?  (Or is there a separate power pin in the connector.)  I'm guessing what you want is to apply a 2MHz sine wave (or pulse) to one and listen with the other and then switch the pulse and listening mode.  If that is the case then how much voltage do you need?  (It's a little strange that the maximum working voltage is less than 200V.  A man might want to ask how much less??? is 190 V OK, 100V??)

Comment: @GeorgeHerold, The exact voltage applied to transducer depends on signal attenuation through the medium, which I am yet to determine, for this reason I would like to have the flexibility to go up to 200V (if need be). Ultrasonic transducer typically require 30mA. (edited my question accordingly, also added operation summary as rightly guessed by George Herold)

Answer (score 1):

OK I'll take a stab at an answer.  I don't know what you have on the receiver end but I'll assume an opamp.  (with +/-15 V rails.)  Then if you could keep the pulse down below 30V p-p you'd be all set.  The problem will be if you have to go to higher voltages.  You can then either protect the input (to the reciever opamp) from the high voltage.  The typical series resistor and diodes to the supply rails.. or by some other scheme.  The other option would be to switch between the Tx and Rx channels.  I think you can do this with a solid state relay (SSR).  But I'm not sure about finding a SSR that works at 2 MHz.  I don't think that would be a problem but I just don't know.  You could also perhaps use mechanical relays, though I don't know how fast they are... what's the settling time for a mechanical relay?  So I'd start with small <30V pulses maybe that will be good enough.  (Turn up the gain on the receiver side.)

Comment: 3.3V is pretty wimpy :^)  What chip?  Does it make the 2MHz too.  More importantly what's on the receiver end?  I was playing with ultra-sonic transducers a few years ago.  I think I was just driving them with a function generator.  (20 V p-p max).  Lot's of opamps will do ~30Vp-p at 2 MHz.  There are a few HV opamps. The LT6090 is in my parts box, but I haven't used it yet.  And certainly an opamp can give you some gain on the receiver end.  (I had an AD825.. but that's just because the receiver gain was taken from another project.. If you've never used opamps..well ask another question. :^)

Comment: In my current design I have a chip that applies a 2MHz sine wave (or pulse) to one sensor and listens with the other sensor and then switches the pulse and listening mode. But the problem is, the chip can supply a maximum of 3.3V @ 98mA, whereas I would like to have the option to increase the supply voltage up to 200V to the transmitter (if feasible, if not I shall try with 30V) and I would also like to have the option to amplify the signal on the receiver (100-300mV). Can this be achieved by just using OpAmps on the receiver and transmitter ? (I have no OpAmps in my existing design).

Comment: Thanks for your effort, Here is the specification (http://www.acam.de/fileadmin/Download/pdf/UFC/English/DB_GP22-DEMO_en.pdf) of the kit which I am planning to use for my project, see figure 2.1 on pg 2-1, note the connector points for transducers (marked as Piezo up, Piezo down), this is where the ultrasonic transducers will be connected. See pg 4-4 for schematic drawing.

Comment: @user44776: I'm confused with your use of the word "power" in that it sounds like you want the transmitting and receiving transducers to swap jobs periodically. That is, XDCR1 is "powered" with a 2MHz pulse and transmits for 20µs, then shuts down while XDCR2 listens for 10ms, then XDCR2 transmits a 2MHz pulse for 20µs, then shuts down while XDCR2  listens for 10ms, and so on... Is that what you want?